# Is there a OS X equivalent to Windows+Shift+Key Left to swap windows from different screens?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes, I have a window on my secondary monitor that I want on my primary (and vice versa).

On my Windows 7 PC, I can press Windows key + Shift + Arrow Left to move the screen right to left. The inverse does what you'd expect.

Is there something similar to this on OS X?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd really love for this feature to be available as well. I went searching right now to even identify what this Windows functionality was referred to as, apparently its `Aero Snap` so the question can be restated as _does macOS have an equivalent to Window's Aero Snap_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "built-in" support for this that I know of.  You could download a third-party application that can do this, though - for example, [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) can do it, but costs $13.